# How to change the interval where checking for internet connection happens from 10 seconds to 5 second or so when using internet connection checker

Tags: flutter

I was using internet connection checker flutter package and couldn't figure out how to change the interval where the checking for internet connection happens from the default 10 seconds?

```
InternetConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen((status) {
    add(OnInternetConnectionChanged(
        status == InternetConnectionStatus.disconnected ? false : true));
  });
```

I want to know where I can change the default interval for checking internet connection from 10 seconds to 5 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For version `0.0.1+4` of the https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker/ the code changed compared to 0.0.1+3.

```
import 'package:internet_connection_checker/internet_connection_checker.dart';

main() async {
  final customInstance = InternetConnectionChecker.createInstance(
    checkTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 1), // Custom check timeout
    checkInterval: const Duration(seconds: 1), // Custom check interval
    // Custom addresses if you'd like it
    addresses: [
      // ...
    ],
  );

  // Register it with any dependency injection framework.
  Get.put<InternetConnectionChecker>(customInstance, permanent: true);
}
```

---

For version `0.0.1+3` of the https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker/
I'd try to override this the similar way as the `addresses`, but in this case it's the `checkInterval` variable:

```
final internetConnectionChecker = InternetConnectionChecker();
internetConnectionChecker.checkInterval = Duration(seconds: 5);
internetConnectionChecker.onStatusChange.listen((status) {
    add(OnInternetConnectionChanged(
        status == InternetConnectionStatus.disconnected ? false : true));
  });
```

I would not modify the package source code.

Comment: ```checkInterval``` cannot be used as a setter as it is final. How to fix this?

Comment: @Arijeet Wow, this commit finalized those variables in April: https://github.com/RounakTadvi/internet_connection_checker/commit/6180ba5357cf16a75070da9a05e80f346f05753c I'll think about how to overcome that. Or file an issue.

Comment: @Arijeet added code: basically you'd instantiate one by yourself the way the example code shows. I haven't tested it, let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker#default_timeout), DEFAULT_INTERVAL is 10 seconds. Interval is the time between automatic checks.

checkInterval (which controls how often a check is made) defaults to this value. You can change it if you need to perform checks more often or otherwise.

```
Duration checkInterval = Duration(seconds: 5);
```

I didn't look too deep into this, but I managed to change it in the source code, and I think thats how its supposed to be done.

How to change it:

1- Right click on InternetConnectionStatus and go to definition.

2- Then cntr + f Duration checkInterval

3- Change `Duration = checkInterval = DEFAULT_INTERVAL` to `Duration = checkInterval = Duration(seconds: 5);`

Comment: Where do I do this exactly?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some code, so I can help you out

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Not helpful at all.